# Continous function to be solved by using intermediate value property

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

A continuous function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ attains each of its values finitely many times and $f(0) \neq f(1)$.

Show that $f$ attains at least one of its values an odd number of times

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: I wasn't getting any idea how to proceed that's why I posted it

Comment: The only way you can have "no idea" is if you never even tried in the first place. So, either you tried something (in which case, even if it's wrong, tell us what you tried and why it didn't work), or you really tried nothing at all (in which case, go try at least something before posting the question...).

Comment: I have surely tried it i was thinking about a interval (p,q) subset of  (0,1) and then a value x in (p,q) which attains a value and simlarly other intervals but wasn't getting any idea how to show it will attain

Comment: Odd number of times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Assume wlog that $f(0)<f(1)$. Start by showing that in the interval $f([0,1])$ there are at most a countable set $E$ of local maximum/minimum values of $f$. Since $(f(0),f(1))$ is uncountable there exists $y\in (f(0),f(1))\setminus E$. By using intermediate value property, show that the cardinality of $f^{-1}(y)$ is odd.

Comment: I am stuck on the point of cardinality can you please explain in brief.

Comment: @user476538 if $f^{-1}(y)=\{x_1<x_2<\dots<x_n\}$ then, since $y\not \in E$, $f(x)-y$ changes sign in each interval $(0,x_1)$, $(x_1,x_2)$, ... ,$(x_{n-1},x_n)$, $(x_n,1)$. But $f(x)-y$ should be negative in the first one and positive in the last one. What is the parity of $n$?

Comment: The parity of $n$ is even

Comment: Got your point then the last term of the interval must be odd. Thank you